# System.NullReferenceException: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Tags: c#

Всем привет. Пишу игру "Сапёр", работающую из окна консоли. Возникает ошибка на участке кода:

```
                    field = new cell[ySize][];
                    for (int i = 0; i<ySize; i++)
                        field[i] = new cell[xSize];
                    // инициализация генератора случайных чисел
                    Random rnd = new Random();        
                    int n=0;

                    // расставим мины
                    do
                    {
                    int row= rnd.Next(ySize); //координата мины по Y
                    int col=rnd.Next(xSize); //координата мины по X

                    if (field[row][col].cheсkNearCell()!= (-1))
                        {
                        field[row][col].setMine();

                        if (row != 0 && col != 0) field[row - 1][col - 1].newMineNear();
                        if (row != 0) field[row - 1][col].newMineNear();
                        if (row != 0 && col != xSize - 1) field[row-1][col + 1].newMineNear();
                        if (col != 0) field[row][col - 1].newMineNear();
                        if (col != xSize - 1) field[row][col + 1].newMineNear();
                        if (row != ySize - 1 && col != 0) field[row + 1][col-1].newMineNear();
                        if (row != ySize - 1) field[row + 1][col].newMineNear();
                        if ((row != ySize-1)  && (col != xSize-1)) field[row + 1][col + 1].newMineNear();
                         n++;
                        }
                    }
                    while (n != numberOfMines);
```

В этом участке кода должен заполняться массив, содержащий "клеточки" из которых состоит поле, и расставляются мины. Код компилируется, игра запускается, но выдаёт ошибку

> System.NullReferenceException: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

Я подозреваю, что при заполнении массива массивов не вызывается конструктор класса. Вот код класса Cell:

```
class cell
{
    private bool opend {get; set;} // - посещали ли мы клеточке
    private bool hasMine {get; set;} // - установлена ли в клеточке мина
    private bool hasFlag {get; set;} // - установлен ли в клеточке флаг
    private int minesNear {get; set;} // - мины рядом

    private  cell()
    {
        hasMine=false;
        opend=false;
        hasFlag=false;
        minesNear=0;
    } 

    //установить флаг
    public int setFlag()
    {
        if (hasMine==true)
        {hasFlag=true; return 1;} //1 - мина установлена успешно
            else return 0;
    }

    //установка мины
    public void setMine()
    {
        hasMine=true;
    }

    //добавление информации о мине поблизости
    public void newMineNear()
    {
        minesNear++;
    }

    //проверка этой клетки на наличие мины 
    public int checkThisCell()
    {
        if(hasMine==true)
            return 666; // 666 - означает наличие мины в данной клетке
        else if (opend==false) 
        {opend=true; return minesNear;}
        else return -1; //-1 - означает что мы посещали эту клетку и нужно выбрать другую клетку
    } 

    //проверка соседней клетки на наличие мины
    public int cheсkNearCell()
    {
        if (hasMine==true || opend==true)
            return -1; // -1 - что нужно игнорировать эту клетку
        else return minesNear;
    }

    //отрисовка клетки
    public void show()
    {
        if (hasFlag==true) Console.Write("F"); // - в клетке установлен флаг
        else if (opend==false)
            Console.Write("#"); // - клетка не открывалась ранее
        else if (minesNear==0)
            Console.Write(" "); // - рядом нет мин
        else Console.Write(minesNear); // - есть определённое количество мин
    }
}
```

Comment: Может быть, запустить в режиме отладки, чтобы сразу же увидеть, в какой именно строке ошибка и где именно `null`?

Comment: @SurfinBird отладчик указывает на ошибку в строке `if (field[row][col].cheсkNearCell()!= (-1))` а все значение массива field[][] равны null

Comment: @SurfinBird Благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ @Surfin Bird верный, давайте я объясню, что происходит.

Вы объявили *массив массивов*. Для массива нужно выделять память при помощи `new`, но элементами вашего массива являются одномерные массивы! Под каждый из них тоже нужно выделять память. Получится такая картинка:

```
field ---> [ элемент 0 ][ элемент 1 ][ элемент 2 ][ элемент 3 ]...
                 |           |            |            |
                 |           |            |            |
                 V           V            V            V
                [ ]         [ ]          [ ]          [ ]
                [ ]         [ ]          [ ]          [ ]
                [ ]         [ ]          [ ]          [ ]
                [ ]         [ ]          [ ]          [ ]
```

Вы создали верхнюю строку, но не остальные.

---

Альтернативным решением могло быть выделение прямоугольного многомерного массива. В этом случае вы получаете сразу нужные элементы:

```
Cell[,] field;
// ...
field = new Cell[xSize][ySize];
```

Comment: Прямоугольный массив тут даже логичнее, как и в любых играх на основе прямоугольной доски в общем-то. А если учесть, что ходы делает человек и размер доски не слишком велик <<100k элементов, то можно не думать про эффективность обработки многомерного массива и улучшить читаемость алгоритма.

Answer (score 2):

Похоже, инициализацию нужно заменить на:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ySize; i++){
    field[i] = new cell[xSize];
    for (int j = 0; j < xSize; j++)
        field[i][j] = new cell();
    }
}
```

Comment: В строке `field[i][j] = new cell();` возникает ошибка >Ошибка CS0122: "Mineswepper.cell.cell()" недоступен в силу его уровня защиты
Сборка не выполнена. (00:00:00.4056007)

Comment: @Gidemin: Ну да, вы же сами объявили конструктор приватным. Сделайте его доступным.

Comment: @VladD да, спасибо за помощь. Мне следовало быть внимательней.

Comment: @Gidemin: Пожалуйста! Это нормально, большинство ошибок такие вот мелкие.